# Google Analytics/GTM sometimes tracks the same pageview twice but with a slightly different hostname

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, page-views

We use Google Tag Manager (GTM) to send pageviews and other data to Google Analytics. I'm currently cleaning up our GTM container to make sure the data is getting sent accurately. I'm running into an issue that even though I only have one pageview tag firing, sometimes (it's not every time) I see two records for the same pageview (even though I know I only viewed the page once in testing). One pageview record has hostname "www.mysite.com" and the other pageview record has the hostname "mysite.com". Has anyone else had this issue and can give me a hint as to why this might be happening?

Comment: Are you using Google Tag Assistant (Chrome extension)? If you install that, start recording, and then load the page, it will tell you exactly what has fired and what the data was. I would check that with loading the page starting with the bare domain, and then loading the page starting with the `www` included on the domain, and see if one of those is firing the tag twice.

Comment: @Reve I am using Google Tag Assistant and what's odd is it always only shows one pageview getting fired.